# Android Studio: Dump Java Heap: "How does it work and how do you read it?"

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks

I am having memory issues and for that I am trying to use the android memory monitor to figure out where all my memory goes.

[image]

As you can see in my screenshot I have found the `Dump Java Heap` button but when i press it nothing isn't really happening.

I don't know what is supposed to happen when i press it but i had expected some menu telling me where all the memory is being allocated.

Can someone give a detailed desciption on how to work with the `Memory Monitor` and perhaps a short tutorial on how to read this dump java heap result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these links can help you:

android studio memory monitor:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html#forcing

Memory leak:

https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/finding-memory-leaks

Comment: though i follow the description here. I still get a blank allocation file. Though the monitor clearly says that 316mb has been allocated in total.